# Numpy on python 3

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have ubuntu 12.10.
I tried to install several packages for python like numpy, scipy and matplotlib.
I ran the [command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965336/python-error-no-module-named-pylab):

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib
```

But when I try to import matplotlib on python's (3.2) shell (or even numpy and scipy), I get an error like

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Yet, I tried to lauch python on the linux shell and import the modules: there is no problem there...

Why can I import the modules on python 2.x and not on 3.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You installed the packages for python 2.x. Do:

`sudo apt-cache search numpy | grep 3`

You will get a number of packages listed. From these, on my ubuntu, I would select:

`sudo apt-get install python3-numpy`

Comment: this worked pretty good for numpy and scipy. However, I still can't use matplotlib. I tried installing it through pip (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) and upgrading my system, but I can't import it on python 3...

Comment: do not have experience with installing it myself, but seems not quite trivial on 12.10: (http://joat-programmer.blogspot.com/2012/11/install-matplotlib-on-ubuntu-1210-for.html)