# [Windows 8 Python 2.7.9]Unable to install modules via pip

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a python newbie who is **trying to install packages via pip**. I changed the PATH to C:\Python27\Scripts in the Advanced system settings and typed pip in cmd, e.g. pip install pylab. However, after the package being cleaned up, a long red message is pop up as sth similar as follows,
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):

(some context)

Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\Username\pip\pip.log

and when I write "import pylab" in Python 2.7.9 Shell, this message shows up:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import pylab
ImportError: No module named pylab

May anyone tell me what's wrong with it and how I can fix it so that I can install and import modules in python?

Comment: Check this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965336/python-error-no-module-named-pylab

Comment: Please always add the exact error messages when posting a question.